# Take sorted list of IP addresses and turn them into CIDR or Range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im currently trying to add some IP Addresses from causing issues into a blacklist, I have gathered all the IP addresses which the count is in the thousand ranges. I am trying to convert all the individual IP addresses into ranges or a CIDR. My first approach to this was by sorting the IP addresses out. To do this I used

```
from socket import inet_aton
import struct

(sorted(list_of_ips, key=lambda ip: struct.unpack("!L", inet_aton(ip))[0]))
```

This will sort my Ip addresses in numerical order. Example:

```
192.1.1.1
192.1.1.2
192.1.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.9
192.168.1.19
```

This is just a small example I created and the actual list probably contains like 90% of IP addresses in a /24 or /22 CIDR

The goal here is trying to convert the sorted list into ranges or CIDR like this:

```
192.1.1.1 - 192.1.1.3
192.168.1.4 - 192.168.1.19
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try dictionary instead of sorting a list:

```
result = {}
for ip in list_of_ips:
    sub = ip[:ip.rindex('.')]  # first three segmants, ex: 192.168.1
    hid = int(ip[ip.rindex('.')+1:])  # host id, last segmant
    result[sub][0] = min(hid, result.setdefault(sub, [255, 0])[0])
    result[sub][1] = max(hid, result.setdefault(sub, [255, 0])[1])

print(result)

for key, value in result.items():
    print('{key}.{from_hid} - {key}.{to_hid}'.format(
        key=key, from_hid=value[0], to_hid=value[1]
        ))
```

result is:

```
{'192.1.1': [1, 55], '192.168.1': [4, 19]}
192.1.1.1 - 192.1.1.55
192.168.1.4 - 192.168.1.19
```